# My True Vault Hunter Mode is Bugged

Tags: borderlands-2

This is my first post here. I was playing with my friend the other day on my TVHM and decided I wanted to go solo. After rejoining my own solo game, I ended up in the first area with Claptrap outside without his eye. At first, I was confused and tried to use the fast travel station. I had noticed the first mission - My First Gun - had been completed in the HUD display, but the yellow exclamation mark was still present of the gun locker. When I used the fast travel startion, I had no where unlocked (except DLC) I have a few screenshots of the problem.

EDIT: I use a mac to play BL2

[image]

Comment: can you use the gibbed editor to move your quest?

Comment: @spartacus I have no idea what that is. Mind explaining?

Comment: if you are on the PC, you can use the Gibbed borderlands 2 editor to modify your save game.

Comment: as I EDITTED, I am using a mac

Comment: maybe there's a mac version of the editor?  Or you can have a friend on a PC edit the file for you.  I don't think the file structure changes

Comment: Where is the save file exactly? I have a PC but I don't know how to migrate the file over so I can edit it.

Comment: according to [this link](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/882966056610447307/) its at ~/Library/Application Support/Borderlands 2/WillowGame/SaveData/__numerical_id__/

Comment: TVHM normally starts you on the overlook to the first town.  Can you walk out of his house normally?

Answer (score 2):

You have to get to the place where you started playing co-op and then you can skip the parts that you've already done.

Answer (score 0):

While playing on someone else's game and play through, that only effects their game. If you have completed a quest on someone else's game, if you start working on it you can usually skip the mission to a later part in the story, but this has only happened to me sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is make it too the first town I think an then you can fast travel

Note: I am not positive so please don't get mad