# How do I advance a quest through Gibbed's Save Editor?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am trying to configure a save file to advance a quest but I have no idea how to use [Gibbed's Save Editor](http://blog.gib.me/2013/01/11/borderlands-2-save-editor-revision-146/). Someone care to walk me through? [I need to advance through a problematic part of a quest.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/my-true-vault-hunter-mode-is-bugged) Pics would help.

Comment: Could you provide more details? What platform is the corrupted save file from? What's the issue with the corrupted save file?

Comment: I have a mac, but I am going to migrate the file to a PC to work on it. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111790/my-true-vault-hunter-mode-is-bugged    That's the question I set up for my broken file.

Comment: If it's corrupted, you dun goof'd.  It means that for some reason something (usually through a modder or editor of some sort) messed up, and your account's pretty much a goner.

Comment: @JonathanChow Could you upload the save file through a file hosting website like Mediafire, and edit in the download link in your question? This is so people can test it with Gibbed's Save Editor.

Comment: @retrosaur I was just playing the game. This was before I even discovered gibbed's save editor

Answer (score 7):

Firstly you will need to open your save into Gibbed's Borderlands 2 save editor and move your way to 'Raw' to edit your characters Raw Data.

[image]

Now scroll down until you see `MissionPlaythroughs`. When you find, it navigate your way to the arrow that will open up the collection window. Image below will give assistance if needed.

[image]

Now that you've opened up the collections list you will notice 3 `MissionPlaythroughData` the first one is Playthrough 1 (Normal Mode), the second one is  Playthrough 2 (True Vault Hunter Mode), and the third one is most likely the 'Something Interesting thing' that Gearbox Is planning on when they raise the level cap which will be a Playthrough 3 no doubt. Depending on what playthrough you're on, choose from 1 of 2 existing options available since Playthrough 3 has no data yet. Once you've clicked one of these navigate your way to the `MissionData` collection arrow. Image below will assist you if needed.

[image]

Once you're in your quest information you will notice a lot of quests. There are two ways to look for the quest you REALLY want to edit, #1 is looking to `mission` on the right this will show you the name or "Codename" of the mission, and #2 is seeing if the mission is Active, Not Started, or Failed. Once you've found the mission you want to edit look to `Status` and change the mission to `ReadyToTurnIn` if you want to instantly complete the mission. If you want to complete a few sub objectives, or objectives you will need BL2 to reference the number of requirements. You can access these options by looking to `ObjectiveProgress` and `SubObjectiveSetIndexes` opening one of these will show a set of numbers depending on the quest.

Like I said before you will need BL2 or a wiki to reference the 'complete' number of the mission requirement. Once you have something to reference from you can then modify the numbers and set a certain objective to 'Complete' some missions may be different though whereas 0 Is incomplete and 1 is complete - remember that! Image below will give assistance if needed.

[image]

It may take some time to get a hang of, but its really not that hard if you think about it. It also comes in handy if you have a quest that you're having a really tough time with such as; finding rare monsters or killing a hard raid boss. It also comes in handy if you're making a save from the ground up.

---

<sup>Source: [Borderlands 2 How to Edit Quest Data [PS3/360/PC] by Seth | gamecrave.forumotion.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20130805090722/http://gamecrave.forumotion.com/t396-borderlands-2-how-to-edit-quest-data-ps3-360-pc)</sup>