# Can I continue an old campaign with a new character?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've just began playing the game and I'm not done with the campaign yet but I'd like to start playing with Zer0 without losing the advance. Can that be done, or do I have to start a new one?

Comment: Officially no, with save editors : no problem (if you play on PC, I don't know much about save editor for console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different characters, different campaigns. You have to start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the techniques found in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/111944/how-do-i-advance-a-quest-through-gibbeds-save-editor). It covers how to use a save editor very comprehensively.

Other than that, you'd have to start a new campaign.