# Is it possible to generate a leveled character in borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2, cheats

In borderlands 2 for steam,is it possible to generate a character at a specific level and story mission point for the standard multi-player campaign?

Reason: I played borderlands 2 some years ago fully by myself. Then I played it again with my brother. Now that I'm married I started playing it with my wife but we are proceeding slow. A friend then also got interested and wants to play with me and we work on catching up with my wife to play 3 of us. And now his girlfriend also wants to join and I'm really tired of playing the story from start. Is there a way for her to generate a character that is a good fit with ours? Means the levels and the story mission fit?

I noticed that the game files are all saved locally on the computer. So I guess it should be possible to manipulate them in a way that they think the character is a normal one?

Comment: While it is possible to manually edit the mission completion status and campaign progress of a character using Gibbed, it seems far easier to just copy your existing character and change the class, as @SeanC has described. Here's a video showing the process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLIeb_ZZCIs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/4797) and  [How do I advance a quest through Gibbed's Save Editor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111944/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja thanks for the links. I would argue they are not exact duplicates as I want to create a new character not advance an existing one. But the solution is probably the same it seems and maybe easier with existing characters. However that is not something I knew before asking

Comment: @findusl You can edit the save game file of a newly created character anyway, same as an existing one.

Comment: @galacticninja As I said, the solution is probably the same. But the question is different. So I do not think it's a duplicate. Don't get me wrong I am grateful for the links, I just want to prevent the question being closed as a duplicate, because it's not a duplicate. Anyone asking my question may not know that it's just the same as changing an existing character or uses the same tool and may therefore not find or recognize the other questions as what he is asking.

Comment: @findusl I'm arguing that they are the same. (I'm talking about the question, [How do I set my level, unlocked weapon equip slots and playthrough mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/111815/4797) - not the other one.) "Is it possible to generate a leveled character in borderlands 2?" is also what is asked about in that question, and is fully covered there. It's about setting a level on a character, existing or new. If this gets closed, it will point to the other question anyway, so other users with similar issues will still find solutions.

Comment: @galacticninja you have a point. I was mainly looking at the first duplicate you mentioned. Because that one definitely isn't a duplicate. Feel free to close if you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Gibbed](https://github.com/gibbed/Gibbed.Borderlands2/releases) will help edit a character.
One way I got my wife's character to my level was to copy my save, then use Gibbed to change the character class. With a short amount of play, she got her character decked out in weapons she preferred.

There is also the option to start a character at [level 30](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/c0wn1x/how_to_start_at_lvl_30/), if that would be easier than having to rely on an external program